# React pass state values to var not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have been returning to react after some break and try to copy me state to :

```
var {email, password } = this.state;
```

From some reason i got the error :

> ReferenceError: password is not defined at eval (eval at...

Can't really figure it out way I have such error on a simple stuff.
Working on version :

```
"react": "^16.7.0",
```

And me code is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { login } from '../actions/loginActions';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      token: "",
      redirect: false

    };

    this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this)
    this.onLogout = this.onLogout.bind(this)
  }
  handleUpdateEmail = (e) =>{
    console.log('handleUpdateEmail: '+e.target.value)
    this.setState({email: e.target.value});

  }
  handleUpdatePassword = (e) =>{
    console.log('handleUpdatePassword: '+e.target.value)
    this.setState({password: e.target.value});
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.state =  { token: localStorage.getItem('token') }
  }

  onLogin = () => {

    var { email, password } = this.state;
    let data = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password    
    }
    this.props.dispatch(login(data));
  }

  onLogout = state =>{
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }
  render() {
    const { redirect } = this.state;
    if (redirect) {
      return (
        <HashRouter>
        <Route path='/' component={() => window.location = '/'}/>
        </HashRouter>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
      <form onSubmit={this.onLogin} >
        <label>
        Username:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" onChange={this.handleUpdateEmail}/>

        </label>
        <label>
        Password:
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleUpdatePassword} />

        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    logs: state

  });
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

How should I approach this kind of error?
And probably how to solve this issue?

--EDIT--
After me friends below help me I understand that the issue is that the function

> ```
>     this.props.dispatch(login(data));
> ```

call before data get the state values .
how can i force it to wait until the data is set?

Comment: where is the instruction `var {email, password } = this.state;` in your code ?

Comment: in function onLogin

Comment: your code seems to be correct. Are you sure the error comes from the `onLogin` function ? you have `var { email, password } = this.props;` instead of `var { email, password } = this.state;`

Comment: I know so how come I can't pass the value:(

Comment: pass to props and after that try to fetch from props not work as well

Comment: oh yeah `componentWillMount` overrides the state initialization in your constructor

Comment: Could you show us the login action method ?

Comment: just solve it , forgot to catch the data on the fetch login function

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `componentWillMount` which is now deprecated, you should initialize the whole state inside your constructor, you should not reassign the state after that, for future update you should use `this.setState`

```
 constructor (props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     email: "",
     password: "",
     redirect: false,
     token: localStorage.getItem('token')
   };

   this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this)
   this.onLogout = this.onLogout.bind(this)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that could lead to an error in my opinion.

1. ComponentDidMount should make use of ComponentInstance.setState method

```js
componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({ token: localStorage.getItem('token') })
}
```

2. The onLogin method is referencing to props instead of state

   ```
   var { email, password } = this.props;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   var { email, password } = this.state;
   ```
3. The connection to redux seems confusing since it is passing the whole state as logs property to the component

Comment: i have change it back to this.state , and after removing the     this.props.dispatch(login(data));
i can console the data info

Answer (score 0):

In the onLogin function you trying to get email and password from the props instead of the state.